# Populate table nested set Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, doctrine-1.2, nested-sets

I'm trying to populate a table set with more root Locations nested three levels: Region, Province and City.

the data to save them from an excel file I'm reading.

i write this script:

```
function importLocations()
{

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("./data/elenco_comuni_italiani_30_giugno_2011.xls");

    $locationTable = LocationTable::getInstance();
    /* @var $tree Doctrine_Tree_NestedSet */
    $tree = $locationTable->getTree();

    $startRow = 2;
    $indexRegion = 0;
    $indexProvince = 2;
    $indexCity = 1;

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($indexRegion);
    $objWorksheetRegion = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRowRegion = $objWorksheetRegion->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumnRegion = $objWorksheetRegion->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumnRegion);
    for ($rowRegion = $startRow; $rowRegion <= $highestRowRegion; ++$rowRegion) {
        $region_name = $objWorksheetRegion->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $rowRegion)->getValue();
        $region_id = $objWorksheetRegion->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $rowRegion)->getValue();
        // create a new root in the tree
        $tree->createRoot($nodeRegion = $locationTable->createNode($region_name));
        echo "\n\Process to Region: $region_name \n";
        //province
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($indexProvince);
        $objWorksheetProvince = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $highestRowProvince = $objWorksheetProvince->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumnProvince = $objWorksheetProvince->getHighestColumn();
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumnProvince);
        for ($rowProvince = $startRow; $rowProvince <= $highestRowProvince; ++$rowProvince) {
            $province_name = $objWorksheetProvince->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $rowProvince)->getValue();
            $province_code = $objWorksheetProvince->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $rowProvince)->getValue();
            $province_region_id = $objWorksheetProvince->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $rowProvince)->getValue();
            $province_id = $objWorksheetProvince->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $rowProvince)->getValue();
            if ($province_region_id == $region_id) {
                //create province node and append it to the region
                $nodeProvince = $locationTable->createNode($province_name, $province_code);
                $locationTable->appendNode($nodeProvince, $nodeRegion);
                echo "Process to Province: $province_name \n";
                //city
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($indexCity);
                $objWorksheetCity = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
                $highestRowCity = $objWorksheetCity->getHighestRow();
                $highestColumnCity = $objWorksheetCity->getHighestColumn();
                $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumnCity);
                for ($rowCity = $startRow; $rowCity <= $highestRowCity; ++$rowCity) {
                    $city_name = $objWorksheetCity->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $rowCity)->getValue();
                    $city_province_id = $objWorksheetCity->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $rowCity)->getValue();
                    $city_region_id = $objWorksheetCity->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $rowCity)->getValue();
                    if ($city_region_id == $province_region_id && $city_province_id == $province_id) {
                        //create province node and append it to the region
                        $nodeCity = $locationTable->createNode($city_name);
                        $locationTable->appendNode($nodeCity, $nodeProvince);
                        echo "Process to City: $city_name \n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Locations Salvate con Successo! \n\n\n";

}
```

and my LocationTable:

```
/**
 * LocationTable
 *
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 */
class LocationTable extends Doctrine_Table
{

    const LEVEL_REGION = '0';
    const LEVEL_PROVINCE = '1';
    const LEVEL_CITY = '2';

    /**
     * Returns an instance of this class.
     *
     * @return object LocationTable
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return Doctrine_Core::getTable('Location');
    }

    /**
     * Developer MUST CALL $parent->refresh() before insert a new node, otherwise
     * following insertions are wrong
     *
     * @param Location $son
     * @param Location $parent
     * @link http://trac.doctrine-project.org/ticket/928
     */
    public function appendNode(Location $son, Location $parent)
    {
        // internally calls save both on parent and son
        $son->getNode()->insertAsLastChildOf($parent);
        // load new parent lft and rgt values
        $parent->refresh();
    }

    /**
     * Build a tree node, save it and return it
     *
     * @param string $label
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return Location
     */
    public function createNode($label, $code = null)
    {
        $node = $this->create(array('name' => $label, 'code' => $code));
        $node->save();
        return $node;
    }
}
```

my doctrine schema:

```
Location:
  tableName: locations
  actAs:
    NestedSet:
      hasManyRoots: true
      rootColumnName: root_id
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    code:
      type: string(2)
```

the problem is that when I go to check a given node, we examine a province, if I perform a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE lft >= x AND rgt <= y
```

I can not find the city that I expect to find, but I find much more.

the scritp that reads excel file it works perfectly. I printed and read all the output and correct. 
I think there is something wrong in the lft and rgt values ​​saved. 
You know you have found a few bugs in the documentation that is not prensa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `hasManyRoots` set in your definition. That means, that your nested set table contains several trees. in each tree `lft` and `rgt` are built independent of other trees, so querying with `SELECT * FROM locations WHERE lft >= x AND rgt <= y` retrieves nodes from several trees.

You have two options to fix it: quick and right.

The quick one:

Every record has a `root_id` (set in `rootColumnName` attribute, it is also the default value) column. This column contains the `id` of the tree's root node. So, if you have to know the `root_id` of your desired node and use it like

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE lft >= x AND rgt <= y and root_id = rid
```

The right one:

Don't query the db directly. Fetch the desired record from the DB as object (e.g. with `DQL`) and than traverse it using `getChildren` or `getDescendants`:

```
// Get the node into $provincevar
$all_cities_in_province = $province->getDescendants();
```

See [NestedSet documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/hierarchical-data/en) for more detailed explanation.

And a little note: that might be a coincidence, absence of caching or something else, but it looks like Doctrine immidiately flushes changes made by `NestedSet` node manipulation functions (e.g. `createRoot`, `delete`, `insertAsLastChildOf` etc.). But that is my observation made on single machine with development environment.